# Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'corecrt.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Just completed the fresh installation of Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 with no optional features, 
[image]
tried running simple code with c++ console app project type:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "testing vs 2019" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Getting below error:

1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(434,5): warning MSB8003: The WindowsSDKDir property is not defined. Some build tools may not be found.

1>Source.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\crtdefs.h(10,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'corecrt.h': No such file or directory
1>Done building project "Project1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you should download and install the Windows 10 SDK in the VS2019 installer.

[image]

The selected version needs to be the same as the version set in the project.

[image]

Comment: @Pankaj, If your case has been resolved, please mark the answer as the correct one and this will be beneficial to others.

Comment: Why is the Windows SDK required for building apps that don't require Windows API calls?

Comment: The Windows SDK contains the C runtime headers and libraries since Visual Studio 2015, so it's required to build virtually any C/C++ program.

Answer (score 0):

install the universal CRT SDK - refer the article here [Universal-crt](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/introducing-the-universal-crt/)