# Build errors in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build-error

Recently, I want to develop a simple app and I started to use Visual Studio. Therefore, I am not familiar with it. I started with a simple "Hello World" code, which is the default one. However, the build errors happen and the system said it cannot find the designated file. I have no idea how to fix them. Below is the error code:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>test.cpp
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\yvals.h(12,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory
1>Done building project "test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Edit:

[image: From Visual Studio Installer]

[image: From Visual Studio > Project > Properties]

Edit 2:

[image: The VC++ Directories Page]

[image: From VoidTools Everything]

Comment: Ensure you installed a Windows sdk when you installed vs and that your project settings are set to use a sdk version that's installed

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks for your suggestion. I am not much familiar with the setting in Visual Studio. Therefore, I don't know whether I do it correctly. Please check my uploaded images above.

Comment: This post is the same issue (though different source header): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685202/how-do-i-get-crtdbg-h-file - I know you installed the Windows SDK but there may be additional steps you need to follow, such as simply rebooting your computer so your environment variables are updated, for example.

Comment: @Dai I have rebooted my computer already but seems the build errors still happen.

Comment: Did you install the Windows SDK after you created your project / solution ?

Comment: One option when "something than cannot happen" still happens, is to run the Repair option in the installer. I can confirm that the file **is** part of the Windows 10 SDK on my machine.

Comment: @BoP Sorry for the late reply. I have just repaired it. Still can't... But also thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @SCMS Please show us the "VC++ Directories" page.

Comment: @SCMS Also, please install [VoidTools Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) and use that to see if `crtdbg.h` is on your system at all (Windows' built-in file search is _awful_).

Comment: @Dai I have uploaded the required photos. Please check. From the Everything app, I found the crtdbg.h file in this location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt
I don't know whether it is correct and what should I do next. Also, thanks for your advice.

Comment: Can only confirm that the images match the settings I have. And here it works...

Comment: Have you read this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58946328/microsoft-visual-studio-community-2019-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-f)?This might help you.

Comment: @YujianYao-MSFT Thanks for your advice. However, I have already checked that the Window SDK version is matched with the one that was downloaded from the installer. Please check for the first and second photos in Edit.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I installed Visual Studio 2022 on 3 of my computers running windows 10 (I wondered if I was just my Main PC acting up), but my new Windows 11 PC worked fine.
After much tinkering I found the if I removed the windows 10 SDK from the Visual Studio installer and then installed it directly (from the stand-alone downloader and not through Visual Studio), did a reboot it all works!

Comment: Thanks for telling me. I'll try it when I have time.